# Should I use a progressbar if its use doesn't necessarily imply progress?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I'm making a web game which I'd like to be accessible, and I wonder whether to keep track of certain stats using the aria progressbar, since its name doesn't really imply it should be used for this sort of thing. However, the spec doesn't state that it shouldn't decrease, (as expected for things like HP and such) so I'm left scratching my head.

Could someone who is more well-informed in accessibility tell me whether I should use this role, or whether I'd be better off creating a generic live region that announces these changes?

Comment: Might be a better question for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a progressbar for HP is fine.  You are making progress towards death, so to speak.  But keep in mind that if a progressbar's value is updated, its new value is not announced to screen reader users unless the focus is on the progress bar.  To have changes announced anytime the progressbar is updated (without focus), you'd need `aria-live`.  (**Note**: `<progress>` is not natively focusable.  It's treated like static text.)

The main purpose of using `<progress>` is for a visual affect.  It seems to be supported on all browsers, https://caniuse.com/#search=progress, but is not supported with all screen readers.  NVDA (pc) and VoiceOver (iOS) will annuonce its value when you navigate to it using the screen reader navigation keys, but JAWS (very popular screen reader on the pc) will ignore it.

Also, for screen readers that honor the `<progress>`, a percentage is announced for the value and not an actual value.  So if you had `<progress value="22" max="50">`, the value would be announced as "44%" and not "22".

It's up to you if you want to hear a number or a percentage.

You could also consider a `<meter>` but Internet Explorer doesn't honor it, https://caniuse.com/#search=meter.

Personally, I think your best bet is to use an `aria-live` region, specifically, `role='status'`, https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#status.

Comment: Does JAWS not support `role="progressbar"`? Also, to support JAWS, is it perhaps best to use a `<progress>` element with `aria-labelledby` pointing to a `role=status` element? Or do you think I should forego `<progress>` entirely?

Comment: From my testing, JAWS supports `role='progressbar'` but does not seem to support the native `<progress>` element.  If you want the visual of a `<progress>`, you can use it and set `aria-hidden='true'` and then have a nonvisual element with `role='progressbar'`.  But neither is really necessary if you have an `aria-live` region to update the HP.